# How do I exclude inputted punctuation from the user using String Tokenizer?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter, stringtokenizer

I have seen similar questions to this problem and the answer on the Stack Overflow did not seem to satisfy the problem. I heard that you need to use `use.Delimeter`, however, I never used it before and want to know how to use it to exclude punctuation from a string that the user inputs. The assignment prompt question is here:

Change the CountWords program (Listing 3.10) so that it does not include punctuation characters in its character count. Hint: You must change the set of delimiters used by the StringTokenizer class.

Here is Listing 3.10:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ThreeEight {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int wordCount = 0, characterCount = 0;
        String line, word;
        StringTokenizer tokenizer;
        System.out.println("Please enter text (type DONE to quit):");
        line = scan.next();
        while (!line.equals("DONE")) {
            tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word = tokenizer.nextToken();
                wordCount++;
                characterCount += word.length();
            }
            line = scan.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Number of words: " + wordCount);
        System.out.println("Number of characters: " + characterCount);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Please enter text (type DONE to quit):
>       Hello World! @#$%^&*():"<>?~/*\
>       DONE
>       Number of words: 3
>       Number of characters: 29

As you can see, it does not count punctuation, what code would I use to exclude the punctuation? I used `use.Delimeter` but it said that it was an invalid method.

Comment: which characters (list of the chars) do you consider punctuations?

Comment: The assignment didn't say which specific kinds, it just said "punctuation marks" I am guessing that means about everything that is not a word or number

Comment: Sorry, had no time. Have you solved it or do you still need help?